# Google Chrome calling nypost.com every ~5 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, little-snitch

I'm using Chrome 21.0.1180.49 beta on Mac OS X 10.7.4.

Did some Googling and can't figure this out.

I visited a page on nypost.com earlier this morning. Just noticed that Little Snitch is reporting that nypost.com is being called every 4-6 seconds or so. I closed the tab after reading the story, a few hours ago.

I created a rule in Little Snitch denying access to nypost.com, but Chrome is apparently still connecting to it.

(1) Why? and

(2) How can I put an end to this?

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Does restarting chrome fix the problem?

Comment: That Little Snitch program is quite pointless considering the Same Origin policy, isn't it? I mean, in most cases it is probably ok if google wants to connect with google. (as for your problem either you have a tab or an extension of nypost active somewhere, try restarting as @soandos suggests)

Comment: @Mahn [Little Snitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Snitch) is simply the tool being used to monitor outgoing traffic from the machine. What does this have to do with the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I thought I read somewhere it was a tool sitting in the browser listening to ajax requests but it looks more like a traditional firewall.

Comment: Which extensions do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Does it still happen after you completely close Chrome and restart?

If so:

1. Disable all your plugins / extensions / etc.
2. Go to chrome://net-internals/ in a new tab and capture the traffic. Find out any referrers, etc. which are triggering this traffic.
3. Kill whatever process is triggering the traffic from #2

If it still happens, complain on the user forums and offer to provide a HAR file and someone from Google will probably contact you in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/). Enable blocking and enable the auto-update feature. Enjoy.